# I need to delete a row from an array if one of the array elements is equal to a value. Using Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel

I have copied an Excel table to an array.

```
Sub
    Dim Mentors As Variant
    Mentors = Worksheets("Mentors").ListObjects("Mentors").DataBodyRange.Value
end sub
```

Now I would like to loop through the Mentors array to find rows with invalid values and delete those rows from the array, but I don't know how to do that.

Then I will put the array back in the table. (That I know how to do).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a row from an array is a pain, it would be easier to work directly on your table:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim x As Long

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Mentors")

For x = tbl.ListRows.Count to 1 step -1
    If your_delete_conditions_go_here Then
        tbl.ListRows(x).Delete
    End If
Next x
```